# Who issues the Type Certificate in the UK?

Tags: aircraft-certification, uk

Who issues a type certificate in the UK, I think in the US it is the FAA?

Answer (score 2):

*Summary:* Aircraft type certificates in the UK were issued by the European Aviation Safety Agency (**EASA**) until January 2020. Since February 2020 they are issued by the UKs Civil Aviation Authority (**CAA**).

---

In the European Union, all aircraft type certificates are issued by EASA since 2003:

> Before a newly developed aircraft model may enter into operation, it must obtain a type certificate from the responsible aviation regulatory authority. Since 2003, EASA is responsible for the certification of aircraft in the EU and for some European non-EU Countries. This certificate testifies that the type of aircraft meets the safety requirements set by the European Union.

<sup>([EASA: Aircraft certification](https://www.easa.europa.eu/en/domains/aircraft-products/aircraft-certification))</sup>

Since February 2020 the UK is no longer a member state of EASA:

> The United Kingdom withdrew from the European Union on 31/01/2020 at midnight (Brussels time) and is now a Third Country.

<sup>([EASA: United Kingdom](https://www.easa.europa.eu/en/domains/international-cooperation/easa-by-country/countries/united-kingdom))</sup>

Type certificates are therefore handled by the UK itself. The responsible authority is the CAA:

> The CAA will issue a Type Certificate (TC) or Restricted Type Certificate (RTC) for the approval of Products (aircraft, engine or propeller) for UK applicants.

<sup>([CAA: Type certificates and restricted type certificates](https://www.caa.co.uk/commercial-industry/aircraft/airworthiness/type-design-approvals/type-certificates-and-restricted-type-certificates/))</sup>

There is however a cooperation between EASA and the CAA as part of the EU-UK Trade and Cooperation Agreement:

> On 24 December 2020, the EU and UK negotiators agreed on a Trade and Cooperation Agreement.
>
> The Agreement applies from 1 January 2021.
>
> Aviation Safety is covered by Part Two, Heading Two, Title II of the Agreement. The application of the agreement is currently limited to airworthiness and environment certification, covered by Annex 30 to the Agreement.

<sup>([EASA: EU-UK Trade and Cooperation Agreement](https://www.easa.europa.eu/en/document-library/bilateral-agreements/eu-uk-trade-and-cooperation-agreement))</sup>

When searching through the rather lengthy agreement (2564 pages), one finds:

> Type certificates issued by the technical agent of the Union as certificating authority shall be
> validated by the technical agent of the United Kingdom as validating authority. [...]
>
> Type certificates issued by the technical agent of the United Kingdom as certificating
> authority shall be validated by the technical agent of the Union as validating authority.

<sup>([Official Journal of the European Union](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=OJ%3AL%3A2021%3A149%3AFULL&from=ES), PDF, p. 1681 f.)</sup>

This means EU type certificates are not automatically valid in the UK, but will be validated by the CAA (therefore no new type certificate needs to be issued). This is similar to the agreement with the US or Canada:

> EASA delivers the primary certification for European aircraft models which are also being validated in parallel by foreign authorities for operation in their airspaces, e.g. the FAA for the US or TCCA for Canada. Conversely, EASA will validate the FAA certification of US aircraft models (or TCCA certification of Canadian models) according to applicable Bilateral Aviation Safety Agreements between the EU and the concerned Third Country.

<sup>([EASA: Aircraft certification](https://www.easa.europa.eu/en/domains/aircraft-products/aircraft-certification))</sup>

There is also a special [Working Arrangement](https://www.easa.europa.eu/en/downloads/132050/en) between EASA and the CAA regarding Rolls-Royce because of the German [Rolls-Royce Deutschland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Deutschland) subsidiary of [Rolls-Royce plc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Holdings), but this is for *engine* certification, not aircraft certification.